# In Highstock, overlapping flags when existing multiple series

Tags: highcharts

I have read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23688459/highstock-two-flags-ond-the-same-xaxis-and-overlapping.

However,my chart has 5 series, after setting *stackDistance=40* and *onSeries: undefined* ,  the flags that have the same date still are overlapping, Is any solutions?

Comment: Could you recreate issue on jSfiddle? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I my also having same issue when multiple series .
Try deducing some formula to detect the overlap and then increase or decrease the Y axis value of the flag to prevent overlap .
Similar issue posted by me on HighChart forum .

http://forum.highcharts.com/highstock-usage/flags-stack-distance-not-working-t32157/

Also i have raised this for enhancement with the highchart team. You can follow this here.

http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/7303396-prevent-flags-overlap